# NLTK, NUMPY and SCIPY - cannot be imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, nltk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i55D.png)

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> python
Python 3.7.0a2 (v3.7.0a2:f7ac4fe, Oct 17 2017, 17:06:29) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> import numpy
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> python
Python 3.7.0a2 (v3.7.0a2:f7ac4fe, Oct 17 2017, 17:06:29) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I can not import the mentioned modules however it is not giving any error as well. Even in small program if I import any of these 3 the program just ends without doing anything.

I have only one installation of Python. No other verison.

Update:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip freeze
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.9.115
botocore==1.12.115
bz2file==0.98
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
docutils==0.14
gensim==3.7.1
idna==2.8
jmespath==0.9.4
nltk==3.4
numpy==1.16.2
python-dateutil==2.8.0
requests==2.21.0
s3transfer==0.2.0
scipy==1.2.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.12.0
smart-open==1.8.0
urllib3==1.24.1
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> python
Python 3.7.0a2 (v3.7.0a2:f7ac4fe, Oct 17 2017, 17:06:29) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(numpy.__version__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined
>>> exit()
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: Same happens for gensim as well.

Comment: Can you check if `print(numpy.__version__)` gives any output, after importing the module?

Comment: No it is not. Updating the question with the output

Comment: Why are you on a Python 3.7 alpha build, and why are you in your system32 directory? Get a stable Python version, and get out of there.

Comment: See https://www.guru99.com/download-install-nltk.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am reading what you have given incorrectly, but the way you have given, you haven’t done any “import numpy” in that Python session before accessing numpy.**version**. Please confirm.

Comment: Another note, doing just an “import” of a module will not produce any output, unless there is an error. So, if the import of numpy is silent then you have successfully imported the library in that Python session.